# Regex for extract months and year combination in a date

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to extract the month and year of pairs of dates in text:

```
regex = (
    r"((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?(t)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)"
    r"\s?[\.\s\’\’\,\/\'\,\‘\-\–\—]?\s?(\d{4}|\d{2})?\s?\s?((to)|[\|\-\–\—])\s?\s?"
    r"((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?(t)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)"
    r"\s?[\.\s\’\’\,\/\'\,\‘\-\–\—]?\s?(\d{4}|\d{2})|(Present|Now|till\s?(now|date|today)?|current)))"
)
```

When I test the regex with some inputs that contain the day of the month in some and not in others:

```
lst = [
    'July 2014 - 28th August 2014',
    'Jan 2012 - 3rd sep 2014',
    'Jan 2008 - May 2012',
    'Jan 2008 and May 2012'
]
for i in lst:
    word = re.finditer(regex,i,re.IGNORECASE)
    for match in word:
        print(match.group())
```

I get the following output:

```
Jan 2008 - May 2012
```

but my expected output is:

```
July 2014 - August 2014
Jan 2012 - sep 2014
Jan 2008 - May 2012
```

What do I need to change to make the regex match text with an optional day in the date? When a date string includes the day, it is always an ordinal number with a `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` suffix.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/3O8JCt/1

Comment: I've added back in the assertion that this is about optional *ordinal* day in the inputs, which I think is important. Feel free to tweak and update.

Comment: And thank you for giving us some code with expected outputs! For future reference: the main goal of this site is to build a collection of programming problems and their solutions for everyone to benefit from, and so we aim for the long term value of questions and answers. This also means that posts can be closed if they don't fit the goals, and reviewing to reopen can take some time. Please be patient and do not just delete and repost when reopening doesn't happen quite so fast as you'd like.

Comment: Do you need https://regex101.com/r/3O8JCt/2?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew No it still the matches 'July 2014 - 28th August 2014' but i dont need 28th in the string.

Comment: Ok, try https://ideone.com/Ctw2aG

Comment: thank you so much.but is it impossible match the month and year by ignoring the ordinal day in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "skip" part of a string during a single match operation, so if you have `26th August`, you can't match or capture just `26 August`. In these cases, you either need to capture parts of the match and then concatenate them, or replace the parts you do not need as a post-processing step.

So, here, I'd use the post-process replace approach with

```py
import re


day = r'(?:((?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:\s*(?:st|[rn]d|th))?)\s*)?'
month = r'(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)' 
year = r'(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)'
rx_valid = re.compile( fr'\b{day}{month}\s*{year}\s*[-—–]\s*{day}{month}\s*{year}(?!\d)', re.IGNORECASE )
rx_ordinal = re.compile( r'\s*\d+\s*(?:st|[rn]d|th)', re.IGNORECASE )

lst = [
    'July 2014 - 28th August 2014',
    'Jan 2012 - 3rd sep 2014',
    'Jan 2008 - May 2012',
    'Jan 2008 and May 2012'
]
for i in lst:
    word = rx_valid.finditer(i)
    for match in word:
        print(rx_ordinal.sub("", match.group()))
```

Output:

```
July 2014 - August 2014
Jan 2012 - sep 2014
Jan 2008 - May 2012
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ctw2aG) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3O8JCt/3).